# As3 - Function with unlimited arguments as Movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, arguments

I want to pass to a function an uncertain number of movieclips, sth like this

```
    function Test(...args)
    {
        for(var item in args){
             item.x = 100;
        }
    }
```

But using this method didn't work, any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to use a `for each` loop for your example to work correctly:

```
function Test(...args)
{
    for each(var item:MovieClip in args)
    //  ^^^^
    {
         item.x = 100;
    }
}
```

Better however would be to accept an `Array` or `Vector` holding the MovieClips. This will greatly improve readability of your code later on:

```
function Test(list:Vector.<MovieClip>)
{
    for each(var item:MovieClip in list)
    {
         item.x = 100;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `arguments`; see the [Adobe Reference docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/arguments.html) (for AS3), the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) (for JS) or [this example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fEbAQ/) (for a working example).

[NB: question originally tagged as JS, leaving javascript/jsfiddle in there for reference]

Comment: You're saying MovieClips don't populate into `arguments`? That'd be a surprising violation of the AS3 specs.

Comment: Because you didn't follow the example I provided :)

From the AS3 docs:

_Note: The arguments object is not available if any parameter is named arguments or if you use the ... (rest) parameter._

Stop using '...' and use the 'arguments' object, should work fine.

Comment: I edited my comment, + removed the JS tag i accidentally added, sry
Didn't work with this error : Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: _Note: The arguments object is not available if any parameter is named arguments_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33054/discussion-between-tml-and-igli-kadija)